# Entity reference field pointing to a Configuration Entity

Tags: views, 8, entities

I develop a custom statistics module to log all node views of a chosen bundles, file downloads and the keywords used to filter a view.

Then I build my Entity Log with a user reference (who does the action), a node reference and a file reference. I want to know if I can make a views reference to point the View (as a configuration entity) that the user searched for some keyword.

I don't know if this is crazy... Is it possible to reference a view from an entity?

I'm using drupal 8

Comment: Open-ended questions like "is this possible?" are not helpful for answers. The answer is Yes, this is possible. The message module already does something similar (stores messages that are fieldable with entity references). However I think that if you are logging for reporting, then the best option for scalability (large number of records) is to use a **denormalized/reporting data model** rather than a **transactional data model**.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: @mradcliffe  I interested in how can I implement this "use a denormalized/reporting data model"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no problem, in ui you can configure bundle fields referencing all entity types, content and configuration. And for base fields this is an example from the user entity for a reference field pointing at the configuration entity `user_role`:

```
$fields['roles'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('Roles'))
  ->setCardinality(BaseFieldDefinition::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED)
  ->setDescription(t('The roles the user has.'))
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'user_role');
```

Comment: I found it, also it can reference a view
`$fields['view_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('View'))
      ->setDescription(t('The view ID of the Log entry.'))
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'view')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'type' => 'entity_reference_label',
        'weight' => 1,
      ));`